# iOS Mail: Non-ASCII characters garbled in subject header when followed by whitespace

Tags: ios, email, encoding, mobile-mail

I noticed recently that certain German characters (ß, Ü, Ä/ä, Ö/ö) are displayed incorrectly in the subject header of messages if (and only if) they are followed either by a space or no character (within the subject header). This only affects Mobile Mail on iOS, but not Mail on macOS. Even more mysteriously, the lowercase Umlaut ü is not affected.

The example subject lines `L(ü|ä|ö)` are displayed correctly in macOS Mail, a webmail interface and other clients (like mutt). The message source looks as expected:

```
Subject: =?iso-8859-1?Q?L=FC?=
Subject: =?iso-8859-1?Q?L=E4?=
Subject: =?iso-8859-1?Q?L=F6?=
```

In Mobile Mail, the subject looks like this (as I said, lowercase ü is the only umlaut not affected):

Lü

L�

L�

Does anyone know about this bug in iOS Mail?

Thanks,
Jan

Comment: Which mail application is used to send one of these mails?

Comment: Do you see this when you send a message to yourself from iOS Mail?

Comment: No, this only happens when using mutt (my primary MUA).

Comment: That also happens with É for me. But it produces: ÔøΩ